# open new xml from listAdapter via onClick

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, rss-reader

I have made an rss reader, now I can see the list with the topics.
Next step would be to open a new window with the topics content when I click on an list item.
Would it work like this:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(List<String> rssFeed) {
    if (rssFeed != null) {
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(
                getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                rssFeed));

    }
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
                                long arg3)
        {

        }
    });
```

If yes,
how can I for example open an new window which would only display some text? For example simply "Hello World"

Is the only way to do this to start an new intent? if yes that would mean i need a new class for it?

Or can I just make another `layout.xml`, define a textfield and call it up via its ID?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="HelloWold"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Would that be possible?

If i want to do it via an Intent ill do it in my `onItemClick` method.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity.class);
```

But how do I get my view for `view.getContext` then?

I am pretty much confused :D

EDIT:

**I tried out this:**

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<String> rssFeed) {
                if (rssFeed != null) {
                    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(
                            getActivity(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                            android.R.id.text1,
                            rssFeed));

                }
                ListView lv = getListView();
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
                                            long arg3)
                    {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Activity2.class);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                    }

                });
            }
```

It does not seem to work, also my manifest xml cant find `<activity android:name=".Activity2"></activity>`

**I get this error:**

```
`07-23 13:35:05.019  21802-21802/com.example.MPAK.mpaknewsreader E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.MPAK.mpaknewsreader, PID: 21802
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.MPAK.mpaknewsreader/com.example.MPAK.mpaknewsreader.MainActivity$Activity2}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1767)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1680)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:4038)
            at android.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:1156)
            at android.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:1140)
            at com.example.MPAK.mpaknewsreader.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment$GetRssFeedTask$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:243)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1282)
            at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:4450)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3174)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3925)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:668)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`
```

but it is declared in the manifest xml...it just doesnt find it.

In my MainActivity class I have a class called:

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

    }
}
```

so why it doesnt find it?

Comment: clean you project the then try.

Comment: Activiy can be an inner class??? Try making it an independent class

Answer (score 0):

First define the Activity2.java in manifest like this:

```
  <activity android:name="com.example.hello.Activity2"/>
```

Then define `Intent` like this:

```
           Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

instead of:

```
                  Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Activity2.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```